# Terminology, SAAS, Azure web app run by a customer

Tags: azure, saas, azure-web-app-service

Getting a little confused on terminology

Software as a Service, where you supply your software without any infrastructure requirements on the customer, e.g. Office 365

If we supply our software as an Azure Web App which the customer deploys on their own Azure account, is this SAAS? If not what is it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following article for a better understanding of PaaS, IaaS, and SaaS: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-saas/

Technically, if your customer uses YOUR software on Azure App services they would be running PaaS. This is because they are using the Azure Platform to host their own specialized code rather than taking code offered from Microsoft.